# How can I implement a comparison of one element with all in the array?

Tags: ios

I'm a beginner, don't swear too much! I have a Date array. These are the photos that I transferred to PNG. I walk through the array, comparing one (first) photo with the others, and depending on the computeDistance between the two photos, either add a duplicate to the array, or go further. How can I compare every next photo with everyone else like this ?

```
private func oneSimilar() {
    var idxArray = [Int]()
    
    let originalImage = imageArray.first!
    guard let originalData = originalImage.pngData() else { return }
    guard let originalFPO = featureprintObservationForImage(data: originalData) else { return }
    
    imageArray.removeFirst()
    
    for image in imageArray {
        guard let data = image.pngData() else { return }
        dataArray.append(data)
    }
    
    for idx in dataArray.indices {
        let contest = dataArray[idx]
        
        if let contestFPO = featureprintObservationForImage(data: contest) {
            do {
                var distance = Float(0)
                try contestFPO.computeDistance(&distance, to: originalFPO)
                if distance <= 3.0 {
                    similarData.append(contest)
                    
                    idxArray.append(idx)
                    imageArray.remove(at: idx)
                    //dataArray.remove(at: idx)
                    print("Count \(similarData.count)")
                }
                //ranking.append((contestantOfIndex: idx, featureprintDistance: distance))
                print("Index - \(idx) Distance - \(distance)")
            } catch {
                print("Error computing distancefD between featureprints.")
            }
            
        }
    if similarData.count > 0 {
        for data in similarData {
            guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
            similarImages.append(image)
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Recursion may help but you need to decide what is going to be an exit point otherwise you will receive stack overflow error, lol. What do you mean under "every next photo", added photo duplicates?

Comment: If you want to check every photo with others: create for-loop for original array of images which has second for-loop inside of it which iterates over every other photo except the current photo in the first for-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for idx in dataArray.indices {
  for jdx in dataArray.indices {
     if idx == jdx { continue }
     // Do your checkings
```